# How to get current user from a Django Channels web socket packet?

Tags: python, django, sockets, session, django-channels

I was following this tutorial: [Finally, Real-Time Django Is Here: Get Started with Django Channels](https://blog.heroku.com/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django).

I wanted to extend the app by using Django User objects instead of the `handle` variable. **But how can I get the current user from the received WebSocket packet in my `ws_recieve(message)` function?**

I noticed that both the `csrftoken` and the first ten digits of `sessionid` from the web socket packet match a normal HTTP request. Can I get the current user with this information?

For reference the received packet looks like this:

```
{'channel': <channels.channel.Channel object at 0x110ea3a20>,
 'channel_layer': <channels.asgi.ChannelLayerWrapper object at 0x110c399e8>,
 'channel_session': <django.contrib.sessions.backends.db.SessionStore object at 0x110d52cc0>,
 'content': {'client': ['127.0.0.1', 52472],
             'headers': [[b'connection', b'Upgrade'],
                         [b'origin', b'http://0.0.0.0:8000'],
                         [b'cookie',
                          b'csrftoken=EQLI0lx4SGCpyTWTJrT9UTe1mZV5cbNPpevmVu'
                          b'STjySlk9ZJvxzHj9XFsJPgWCWq; sessionid=kgi57butc3'
                          b'zckszpuqphn0egqh22wqaj'],
                         [b'cache-control', b'no-cache'],
                         [b'sec-websocket-version', b'13'],
                         [b'sec-websocket-extensions',
                          b'x-webkit-deflate-frame'],
                         [b'host', b'0.0.0.0:8000'],
                         [b'upgrade', b'websocket'],
                         [b'sec-websocket-key', b'y2Lmb+Ej+lMYN+BVrSXpXQ=='],
                         [b'user-agent',
                          b'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) '
                          b'AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version'
                          b'/10.0 Safari/602.1.50'],
                         [b'pragma', b'no-cache']],
             'order': 0,
             'path': '/chat-message/',
             'query_string': '',
             'reply_channel': 'websocket.send!UZaOWhupBefN',
             'server': ['127.0.0.1', 8000]},
 'reply_channel': <channels.channel.Channel object at 0x110ea3a90>}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note**: The question is specific to `Channels 1.x` and the `Django` session system, if you're here for `Channels 2.x` way, please read the docs from the link below, they're more than clear on how to do this, the `Channels 1.x` docs were confusing for some people (including me), this is why this question and others were made, the `Channels 2.x` docs are crystal clear on how to achieve this:
https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/authentication.html#django-authentication

---

## **Channels 1.x:**

You can get access to a `user` and `http_session` attributes of your `message` by changing the decorators in `consumers.py` to match the docs:

> You get access to a user’s normal Django session using the `http_session decorator` - that gives you a `message.http_session` attribute that behaves just like `request.session`. You can go one further and use `http_session_user` which will provide a `message.user` attribute as well as the session attribute.

so the [`consumers.py`](https://github.com/jacobian/channels-example/blob/4b9765630d94c0c433829d06039a4e57c065df86/chat/consumers.py) file in the example should become the following:

```
from channels.auth import http_session_user, channel_session_user, channel_session_user_from_http  

@channel_session_user_from_http  
def ws_connect(message):  
    ...  
    ...


@channel_session_user  
def ws_receive(message):  
    # You can check for the user attr like this  
    log.debug('%s', message.user)  
    ...  
    ...  


@channel_session_user  
def ws_disconnect(message):  
    ...  
    ...
```

**Notice the decorators change**.
Also, i suggest you don't build anything upon that example

for more details see: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/1.x/getting-started.html#authentication

Comment: Thanks, for the help! If I understand correctly `channel_session_user` adds `message.user` attribute, but I would still need to use `channel_session` to persist other data right?

Comment: yes, the docs say this: ```Channels provides a channel_session decorator for this purpose - it provides you with an attribute called message.channel_session that acts just like a normal Django session.```

Comment: link is broken: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started.html#authentication

Answer (score 9):

Updated answer in 2018 [via the docs](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/authentication.html):

> To access the user, just use self.scope["user"] in your consumer code:

```
class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self, event):
        self.user = self.scope["user"]

    def receive(self, event):
        username_str = None
        username = self.scope["user"]
        if(username.is_authenticated()):
            username_str = username.username
            print(type(username_str))
            #pdb.set_trace() # optional debugging
```